# Which of the following decorator is used to assign user defined setup and tear down functions to a test function, while using nose?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, python-decorators, nose

I am not able to choose the right answer for this please help

1. @use
2. @with_setup
3. @use_setup
4. @setup

Any help is highly appreciated ! !

Plss help

Answer (score 0):

@with_setup

@with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
def test():
"test ..."